# Connection without TCP/IP over Internet

Tags: web-services, networking, ip, tcp

Today I am thinking about connect two computer without tcp/ip. Actually i am searching: connection without ip; if i manage to connect without ip, these network is untraceable.

My full question is :

**It is possible to connect two computer without tcp/ip over internet.**

May these scenario impossible for the ISP. I don't know.

If possible, It can be competitor of Internet.

Comment: IP stands for **_Internet Protocol_**. You, as an end user, certainly don't need TCP, but IP is a requirement, even if it is an IP gateway (used to be used for IPX, SNA, etc. networks before they were converted to IP). The ISPs comprising the Internet _must_ use TCP since they _must_ connect via BGP, and BGP uses TCP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the first line of Wikipedia on `Internet`:

> The Internet is a global system of interconnected computer networks that use the standard Internet protocol suite (TCP/IP) to link several billion devices worldwide.

The internet is **built upon** the IP framework. You can't "not use" IP through the internet. That's like to say I want to use the post system without addresses. Without the IP framework, there is no way to identify devices from each other or have any standard format to route packets anywhere at all. This is not to say that it is the *only* way to establish networked communications, it's just the most popular and most used way.

Regarding the first part of your question: `It is possible to connect two computer without tcp/ip?` There are plenty of ways this is done e.g. Bluetooth, RS-232, proprietary RF communications and so forth.

Also, towards `competitor of Internet` is that really such a good idea? For once we have one system that is universally compatible with all devices around the globe (almost!). I don't think the rest of the world would be keen on a brand new system unless it is much much much better (in which it'll probably be implemented into the Internet Protocol Suite anyway).